# C code to find "Cullen's number"

Tags: c

Need to make a C code that asks of the user to input one number, and the code will check whether the number is a "Cullen's number" or not.

A number is Cullen's number as long as you can calculate it by doing "2^n * n + 1".

Examples of Cullen's numbers:

```
3=2^1 * 1 + 1
9=2^2 * 2 + 1
25=2^3 * 3 + 1
```

Here's the code I was working on, any help?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

    int num, brojP, potency = 0, numRepeats = 0, endResult=0, isCullen;

    printf("Unesite broj");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    do
    {

        potency = potency + 1; // initializing "potency" and at the same time making it one number larger at each repeat of the loop
        do
        {
            brojP = 2*potency;
            numRepeats = numRepeats + 1;
        } while (numRepeats < potency); // this entire loop is used for "2^n" part

        endResult = brojP * potency + 1; // calculate the "2^n * n + 1" 
        numRepeats = 0;

        if (endResult == num)
        {
            isCullen = 1;
            break;
        }


    } while (endResult < num);

    if (isCullen == 1)
        printf("Number inputted is Cullen's number\n");
    else
        printf("Number inputted isn't Cullen't number\n");

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* as there are variables you might not initialize. Uninitialized local variables haven an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: Your loop that's supposed to calculate `2^n` doesn't work. It sets `brojP` to the same thing every time through the loop, so it's just like doing `brojP = 2*potency;` once.

Answer (score 1):

This loop is wrong:

```
    do
    {
        brojP = 2*potency;
        numRepeats = numRepeats + 1;
    } while (numRepeats < potency); // this entire loop is used for "2^n" part
```

You need to multiply the result from the previous iteration by 2 each time, but you're multiplying `potency` by 2 instead. Since `potency` doesn't change, you're just doing the same assignment over and over. Do it like this:

```
    brojP = 1;
    for (numRepeats = 0; numRepeats < potency; numRepeats++) {
        brojP *= 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would maybe be more efficient if you used dichotomic search. As you store your result in an int, I assume that the max size for the entered number is 2^32 (int are most frequently coded on 32 bits).
You can try with potency = 16 and then if the entered number is bigger with 2^24, etc
If (let's say) you try for n = 6 then n = 7 and none of them is working, you know that it is not a Cullen's number.
You will at most calculate log2(32)=5 times.

EDIT: By the way, why don't you just use the math.h library?